# LWJGL glfwGetCursorPos issue

Tags: java, glfw, bytebuffer

For some reason (probably because I'm clueless) this only ever prints `0.0   0.0`

```
ByteBuffer x = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
ByteBuffer y = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
GLFW.glfwGetCursorPos(Window.window, x, y);
System.out.println(x.getDouble() + "   " + y.getDouble());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I forgot to poll events. Derp.